# umranda: non-existent package?

Tags: fonts, errors, packages, miktex2.9

On page 205 of the `symbols-a4` (2020) page table 527 mentions `umranda` Decorative Borders. This package is useful for drawing the fish. Does this package not exist anymore?

This code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{umranda}
\begin{document}
\Pisymbol{umranda}{65}
\end{document}
```

Produces this error:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `umranda.sty' not found.

I don't find `umranda` on CTAN.

Comment: Hi, Sebastiano! `umranda` is not a package, but a font. Did you install `niceframe` and `niceframe-type1`?

Comment: @Bernard Very kind Bernard I not know  that `umranda` needs to install niceframe and niceframe-type1! :-(

Comment: In MiKTeX, `umranda` and `umrandb`, and their type 1 versions  are installed with these packages, along with `bbding`, `dingbat` and `karta15`.

Comment: @Bernard Please could you post an answer with pictures so I understand better? Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure I see what you want.Is it a demo of the use of this font?

Comment: @Bernard Hi, I have used `MikTeX` (new update 2021-4-7) and I have compiled with `TeXworks`. But I have this error: `! LaTeX Error: File umranda.sty not found`. Surely after the egreg's answer I have not installed or download nothing :-(...I will see one day. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do “Search by file” in the CTAN home page and type `umranda` in the box, you'll be directed to https://ctan.org/search?phrase=umranda

[image]

This should suggest to install both [`niceframe`](https://ctan.org/pkg/niceframe) and [`niceframe-type1`](https://ctan.org/pkg/niceframe-type1)

With `tlmgr` from the command line you can do `tlmgr show umranda` and you'll get

```
tlmgr: cannot find package umranda, searching for other matches:

Packages containing `umranda' in their title/description:
niceframe-type1 - Type 1 versions of the fonts recommended in niceframe

Packages containing files matching `umranda':
niceframe:
    texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/niceframe/umranda.mf
    texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/niceframe/umranda.tfm
niceframe-type1:
    texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/niceframe-type1/umranda.afm
    texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/niceframe-type1/umranda.pfb
```

which shows the same information as before. Possibly also the MiKTeX wizard has search features (I can't find them at the MiKTeX site, though).

Comment: I thank you very very much for your explanations. I not know nothing on this umranda.